# C++ Library for 3D Monitor Display

Tags: c++, 3d, monitor

I have 3D point cloud data and I would like to display the output on a 3D monitor. Is there a c++ library that can do this? I would also like the user to be able to pan, rotate, and zoom the point cloud. I am using a nvidia GeForce GT 540M 1GB vram video card.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Point Cloud Library](http://pointclouds.org/) which uses the [Visualization Toolkit](http://www.vtk.org/) to render. They support all basic forms of interaction, and I have used them to render point clouds. I think they would both be good starting points, and they use OpenGL to render. I know VTK has support for 3D displays, but have not used it in that way as I do not have access to a 3D monitor.

Comment: Is there sample code available from VTK to show how to render a 3D display?

Comment: I was guessing from this code documentatrion, http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkRenderWindow.html#a282cb670a25927b806c42c4a76ac9b78 but like I said have never had access to a stereo display to test any of this. This is something that people on the VTK or ParaView mailing lists may know - as i know there are people working in this area.